# Linear Algebra: Vector equation, find the missing integers.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, systems-of-equations

I am stuck at the following math problem:

I am asked to find "r" and "k", which are integers, so that the following equation will hold true, and additionally I have to find "x", "y", "z".

The equation:

r(3, 7, 0, 5) - k(7, 1, 3, 0) = (0, x, y, z)

The answers are: k=3; r = 7;

This is about vectors. And in my textbooks' lectures this case wasn't mentioned and I am stuck on this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Write out the system of equations $r\cdot3 - k\cdot7 = 0\\ r\cdot 7 - k\cdot1 = x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to make the first component of the resultant vector, null. Indeed you have in the right hand side:

$$(0, x, y, z)$$

So you don't care what $x, y, z$ are. You only care to solve

$$3r - 7k = 0$$

And the easiest choice is then

$$r = 7 ~~~~~~~ k = 3$$

The other components won't be zero, so you will get a tern of parameters $x, y, z$ which will be nonzero (or anyway, arbitrary).

What you need, again, is the first component to be zero.

Then, once you understood $r = 7$ and $k = 3$ you will solve the remaining expressions:

$$7(3, 7, 0, 5) - 3(7, 1, 3, 0) = (21-21,\ 49 - 3,\ 0 - 9,\ 35 - 0)$$

so

$$(0, 46, -9, 35)$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Please forgive my incompetence, but how did you get   3r-7k=0    to give   give the result r=7 and k=3 ?

Comment: Oh it's the easiest choice! You could have chosen for $r = 14$ and $k = 6$ too! There are infinite solutions!

Comment: Ah, I get it. So simple indeed. We pick any number for -r- and -k- in order to make the first component in the result to be equal to 0, in this case. I thought I had to go through some sort of systems of linear equations.

Thanks for the prompt assistance! I would vote up, but I am new and I still cannot do that. :(